# Netgear FVX538v2 slow whene connected to Canoga Perkins N525 ETSU

Tags: networking, ethernet, fiber, netgear

First of all thank you in advance for helping me. my issue is the old network admin found a problem whene he connected the firewall and the ETSU together the through put went down to less than 1 mega bit a second. his fix was to add a dlink router between the firewall and the etsu which speed it up to 5 mega bits a second. now my boss wants a more clean and proper solution if possible. i have check all the settings in the netgear it dose not seem to be a setting issue. if anyone can help that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably is just a mismatch in the link's configuration - a [duplex mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_mismatch) seems quite likely. The "d-link router" is probably not doing anything aside from serving as a simple switch which happens to [auto-negotiate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation) to correct values.